# VSTO document level customization with visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, excel-2010, vsto, visual-studio-2017, office-addins

I have developed a simple Excel 2010 document level customisation based on the c# project template provided with VS 2017 community.

Unfortunately I don't have much experience on Office dev but a solid experience with VBA.

It all went ok to code, debug and run the solution till the moment I tried to open an Excel file at the same moment VS had my solution opened.

The document level customisation Excel workbook disappeared. I could not get it back whether running from VS nor opening it from a folder.
I tried cleaning up the solution, uninstalling the documents (they are installed as part of the system with VSTO).

Any clue on the issue ?

Comment: Why try to open the file outside of VS at the same time your compiling and running?  When you compile and run,  VSTO opens the file automatically for you.  Can't tell you for sure why your Workbook "disappeared".  I'd suggest recreating the steps and post.

Answer (score -3):

IN EXCEL you can not open two file which have same name a.xls and a.xls.

"Sorry, Excel can't open two workbooks with the same name at the same time."

So; If you open a file in EXCEL, you can not open it in  EXCEL Desinger.
And in some cases; if you want to open document in EXCEL; EXCEL Desinger in Visual Studio Crashes; And Desinger Generated codes lost. WHEN you reopen that solution you get errors. In order to prevent errors; Backup your Improvments or use TFS

Using WINDOWS 10, Visual Studio 2015, EXCEL 2016 And Visual Studio Tools For Office 2010 I have crash problem. And another problems that I can not properly solve. 
Reverting EXCEL to 2013 resolve some problems for me. I do not see this problem on my old PC which I use; WINDOWS 8.1, VS 2015, EXCEL 2013 And VSTO 2010

Also; WINDOWS 10 And Security Updates are problematic if you use VSTO

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @YasinAlp, your initial post wasn't really answering the question at all, you probably fixed your answer already but I'm going to keep my downvote because of you being disrespectful.